# Robolectric 2 + Eclipse = NoSuchMethodError: ShadowLayoutInflater

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, robolectric

I tried to split the [Robolectric-Sample](https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample) into two projects in Eclipse.

I called it [RobolectricSample-split](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/RobolectricSample-split). First part is the [Android](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/RobolectricSample-split/tree/master/RobolectricSample.android) part and second the [Test](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/RobolectricSample-split/tree/master/RobolectricSample.test) part.

And it drives me nuts!!! Robolectric is a great piece of software but no documentation!
Anyway - the Android-part works. The Test-part shows more then 50% red.

There are mostly **two errors**: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.robolectric.Robolectric.shadowOf(Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;)Lorg/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLayoutInflater;

ShadowLayoutInflater was include in the Robolectric 2 alpha but seems to be generated in the 2.1 now - but not in my case.

**Second error:** org.fest.reflect.exception.ReflectionError: Unable to invoke method 'attach' with arguments [com.pivotallabs.injected.TestApplication@2602585e, null, org.robolectric.RoboInstrumentation@64b041b0, null, 0, com.pivotallabs.injected.TestApplication@2602585e, Intent{componentName=ComponentInfo{com.pivotallabs/com.pivotallabs.HomeActivity}, extras=Bundle[{}]}, null, 'title', null, 'id', null, {0.0 0mcc0mnc de_DE ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp nrml ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}]

**Here are two SS:**
[image: ShadowLayoutInflater]
[image: attach]

Please help!
PS: Yes - I know switching to IJ solves the problem but I think I mature piece of SW like Robolectric should also work with Eclipse and! Gradle